# Linux/bash parse text output, select fields, ignore nulls in one field only

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I've done my requisite 20 searches but I can't quite find an example that includes the 'ignore null' part of what I'm trying to do.  Working on a Linux-ish system that uses bash and has grep/awk/sed/perl and the other usual suspects.  Output from a job is in the format:

```
Some Field I Dont Care About        = Nothing Interesting
Another Field That Doesnt Matter    = 216
Name                                = The_Job_name
More Useless Stuff                  = Blah blah
Estimated Completion                = Aug 13, 2015 13:30 EDT
Even Yet Still More Nonsense        = Exciting value
...
```

Jobs not currently active will have a null value for estimated completion time.  The field names are long, and multi-word names contain spaces as shown.  The delimiter is always "=" and it always appears in the same column, padded with spaces on either side.  There may be dozens of jobs listed, and there are about 36 fields for each job.  At any given time there are only one or two active, and those are the ones I care about.

I am trying to get the value for the 'Name' field and the value of the 'Estimated Completion' field on a single line for each record that is currently active, hence ignoring nulls, like this:

```
Job_04 Aug 13, 2015 13:30 EDT
Job_21 Aug 09, 2015 10:10 EDT
...
```

I started with `<command> | grep '^Name\|^Estimated'` which got me the lines I care about.

I have moved on to  `awk -F"=" '/^Name|^Estimated/ {print $2}'` which gets the values by themselves. This is where is starts to go awry - I tried to join every other line using `awk -F"=" '/^Name|^Estimated/ {print $2}'| sed 'N;s/\n/ /'` but the output from that is seriously wonky.  Add to this I am not sure whether I should be looking for blank lines and eliminating them (and the preceding line) to get rid of the nulls at this point, or if it is better to read the values into variables and printf them.

I'm not a Perl guy, but if that would be a better approach I'd be happy to shift gears and go in that direction.  Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated, Thanks!

```
Some Field I Dont Care About        = Nothing Interesting
Another Field That Doesnt Matter    = 216
Name                                = Job_4119
More Useless Stuff                  = Blah blah
Estimated Completion                =
Even Yet Still More Nonsense        = Exciting value
...
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with NULL? If the name is empty, if the estimate is empty?

Comment: Post an example of the null field.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, not enough reputation... 
But I think something like this will work, in your print command

```
{printf "%s,",$2;next}{print;}
```

Or use paste command?

```
paste -s -d",\n" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
awk -F"=" '/^Name/ {name=$2} /^Estimated/ { print name, $2}' file
```

if they always come in the same order: name first, estimate next.

You can then add a NULL check to the last field and don't print the line if it matches like:

```
awk -F"=" '/^Name/ {name=$2} /^Estimated/ { if($2 != "") {print name, $2}}' file
```

Comment: That second version is very close to working - changed -F"=" to -F" = " from Ed's comment above and it works.  A few extra spaces around the result for some reason, testing with a larger export to verify that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `for some reason` - there's no mystery, with `-F" = "` you are telling awk that 1 (**one**) space on either side of the `=` is part of the Field Separator and so all other spaces before/after that are part of the field.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the bit where I tried "=", " = ", '[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*', and '\\s*=\\s* the first time around.  The latter two both eliminated null lines entirely, and returned the date as expected, but did not return the corresponding name field value.  I now realize that I shouldn't post these things at 3:00AM, as I made an error in the formatting of my input example on the right side of the equal sign - the actual files always have a single space between the equal and the data on the right side.  I've updated the sample to show this.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'\\s*=\\s*' '{a[$1]=$2} /^Estimated/ && $2{print a["Name"], $2}' file
The_Job_name Aug 13, 2015 13:30 EDT
```

Replace `\\s` with `[[:space:]]` if you aren't using gawk, i.e.:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*' '{a[$1]=$2} /^Estimated/ && $2{print a["Name"], $2}' file
```

and if your awk doesn't even support character classes then GET A NEW AWK but in the meantime:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t]*=[ \t]*' '{a[$1]=$2} /^Estimated/ && $2{print a["Name"], $2}' file
```

Comment: This is close - not using gawk (so I've used `-F' = '` in the command).  It doesn't show the nulls, but it also isn't displaying the value of 'Name' either, only the value for the Estimated Completion.

Comment: That's absolutely correct behavior. Now please reread the last line of my answer where I gave the clear, specific, simple instruction on what change to make if you aren't using gawk and then compare that to the change you actually made.